# Linking package to a third folder in Xcode..?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I created a Xcode project that has two targets, ios and watchos; therefore the project was created with two folders, "MyProject" and "MyProject Watch App".

I added the Firebase package by right clicking on the parent directory then "add package". With this, I can add "import Firebase" no problem under these 2 folders.

However I have another folder called "Shared". And when I add "import Firebase" under this folder, I get error message saying "no such module Firebase".

Seems like I am missing a linkage somewhere.. Please help!

Comment: Did you add Firebase as a library dependency?

Answer (score 0):

In the Project Navigator (left sidebar), locate your project's top-level blue project icon and select it.
In the main editor area, you will see the project settings. Click on your project's target under the "Targets" section.
In the target settings, click on the "Build Phases" tab.
Expand the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.
Click on the "+" button to add a new library.
In the dialog that appears, click on the "Add Other" button.
Navigate to the folder where your package is located and select the necessary file or files you want to link.
Click on the "Add" button to add the selected files to your Xcode project.
Verify that the added files appear in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section.